# Oracle Apex Interactive Grid not saving updated values

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm working with an Interactive Grid, while updating a value I get success message but nothing really happens (I update the value, click on save, message pop-up appears: changes saved. But the values remain the same).
This is my query:

```
select 

PRODUCT_SECTION,
PRODUCT_ID,
PRODUCT_NAME,
MIN_QUANTITY,
QUANTITY,  --This is the column available for updates
MY_PRIMARY_KEY

FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE USER = lower(v('APP_USER'))
AND ID = :P31_MY_ID
AND DEAL_ID = nvl(:P31_MY_DEAL, 'No Deal')
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a process of type "Interactive Grid - Automatic Row Processing (DML)"  for with your IG as "Editable Region" ?

Comment: Thanks again! Forgot to mention that I actually have 2 IG on the same page (the one you helped me with before and this other one). Apex only created one for the first IG.
Just duplicated it for the other one and worked. Thanks!